# How to calculate address subtraction in c++

Tags: pointers

I am a little surprised by the output of the following code:

```
double array[] = {4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 20}; 
double* p = array + 3; 
//Print array address
cout << (unsigned long)(array) << endl; //This prints 1768104
cout << (unsigned long)(p) << endl; //This prints  1768128 
//print p - array
cout << (unsigned long)(p - array) << endl; // This prints 3
```

I am surprised that the last line prints 3. Shouldn't it print 24 = 3 * 8 bytes? Also, as expected, 
    the address of p is the address of array + 3 * 8 bytes. This seems inconsistent. 
    In fact, it is not even a legal assignment to write: 
    p = p - array; // can't assign an int to type double*  No idea, why this is an int.

Comment: You are surprised that `p - array == 3` when `p = array + 3`?

Answer (score 2):

Pointer arithmetic works in multiples of the size being operated on.  `p` is `3` `double` sizes greater than `array`, so that's why you get that response.  It's the same reason your `p = array + 3` line worked.

If you want the 24, do your casting differently to operate on byte-sized values:

```
cout << (char *)p - (char *)array;
```

Your statement `p  = p - array` is meaningless - you can't assign an integer (the difference between pointers) to a pointer variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is how [pointer arithmetic](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp7a.doc/language/ref/clrc03ptarith.htm) works.

You may try like  this:-

```
cout << (char *)p - (char *)array;
```